# Correct use of useRouter Next.js?

Tags: next.js

Hi all just a quick question, is this the correct way of using useRouter in Next.js.

```
const router = useRouter();
const route = router.query;

console.log(route.id)
```

When i destructure like this, I get an undefined value. Could anyone help me understand why this happens

```
const router = useRouter();
const {route} = router.query;

console.log(route)
```

Comment: In your second block of code, do you actually meant to do `const {id} = router.query;` instead? Because those 2 blocks of code are not doing the same thing as it is.

Comment: Hello thank you for answer , what is the difference between , {id} and {route} , i thought both were variables.

Comment: Ok maybe i actually misunderstood , so you say that its supposed to be {id} as thats what i have in the object ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. `router.query.id` exists, but `router.query.route` doesn't.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between

```
const route = router.query;
```

and

```
const {route} = router.query;
```

The second one is deconstructing `route` value from `object` returned by `router.query`, hence giving undefined .
Here's the object returned by [router object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object)

[Object deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

Comment: Ahhh i see , thank you so much , the links explain it perfectly .